# Php to C# aspnet mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have transform a php/js code to js/c#, but i stuck for update the new value. 
The php code is :

```
    `if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
        foreach($_POST['positions'] as $position) {
           $index = $position[0];
           $newPosition = $position[1];
           $conn->query("UPDATE country SET position = '$newPosition' WHERE id='$index'");
        }
        exit('success');
      }`
```

My "empty" c# code

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index (userTable index)
    {
        picturesEntities MyDb = new picturesEntities();
        homeViewModel HVM = new homeViewModel();
        HVM.userTables = MyDb.userTables.ToList();

        if (Request["update"] != null)
        {
            foreach (Request["positions"])
            {


                MyDb.SaveChanges();
            }
            return View(HVM);         
        }
    }
```

If someone could help me for it that would be great, i'm stuck on it for days and i didn't find a workning solution yet. 
Thanks to everyone who read my message.

Comment: Where is your country set to update in c# code? You are updating country table in php code but in c# no country exists.

Comment: Hi, my table is userTable (c#), in php was the example i would like to reproduce in C#. I have a table userTable and in that table i have id and position

Comment: @harima34, can you publish raw request example ?

Comment: Hi Orel, the thing is that im not sure that Request is what i need to use, i'm very confused about how to do that step for  transform a php $post into C#.
I link you the code of my Cshtml page and of my controller :
https://codepen.io/harima34/pen/WNvXrPo

Answer (score 0):

Most ASP.NET will bind a custom class which will be compatible to your request.

```
public class UserPositionsRequest
{
    public bool Update { get; set; }
    // For orderly, this actually be a list of a custom class
    public List<int[]> Positions { get; set; }
}
```

This by any means is not a complete and working solution, the following code was never been tested and can be consider as pseudo-like code.
Also, the `.Id` and `.Position` should be the same sensitivity as in Db.

```
// Binding our UserPositionsRequest class
public void Index(UserPositionsRequest request) {
    // Checking if we should update, if you will change the request to boolean type: "true"
    // ..on the client side, then you could actually change the condition to be: if (request.Update)
    if (request.Update == 1) {
        // Creating database connection using (I assume) EntityFramework
        using (var picturesEntities = new picturesEntities()) {
            // Building a dictionary for fast lookup. Key, Value as the 0, 1 arg respectfully
            var usersDataToUpdate = request.Positions.ToDictionary(p => p[0], p => p[1]);
            // Finding the entries that needs to be updated
            var usersEntitiesToUpdate = picturesEntities.userTables.Where(cntry => usersDataToUpdate.ContainsKey(cntry.Id));
            // Iterating over the entities
            foreach (var userEntity in usersEntitiesToUpdate) {
                // Updating their position.
                userEntity.Position = usersDataToUpdate[userEntity.Id];
            }
            picturesEntities.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    // Probably you wanted to return something here, but it's probably an ajax and you can skip that.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your update, after tried i got that error :

System.NotSupportedException : 'LINQ to Entities Doesn't recognize the method 'Boolean ContainsKey(Int32)', and the latter cannot be translated into a store expression. '
at that line : foreach (var userEntity in usersEntitiesToUpdate)